# Reconstruct a reference grid with the combination of two variables from emmeans::ref_grid

Tags: r, emmeans

My real data is of similar complexity to the ideas that `emmeans:MOats` wants to convey. I am using `MOats` as a practice example.

```
library(emmeans)


MOats.lm = lm(yield ~ Block + Variety, data = MOats)
    ref_grid(MOats.lm)
'emmGrid' object with variables:
    Block = VI, V, III, IV, II, I
    Variety = Golden Rain, Marvellous, Victory
    rep.meas = multivariate response levels: 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6
    # Silly illustration of how to use 'mult.levs' to make comb's of two factors
    ref_grid(MOats.lm, mult.levs = list(T=LETTERS[1:2], U=letters[1:2]))
```

Assuming that the `Block` factor in `MOats.lm` is not the popular blocking factor in experiment design, but a characteristic of Oat.

Main question: I want to create a new variable from the combination of `Variety` and `Block`, called `eater` with `add_grouping` syntax, such that if `Variety = Golden Rain x Block = I` then `eater = fox`, if `Variety = Golden Rain x Block = II` then `eater = fox`, if  `Variety = Marvellous x Block = II` then `eater = cat`, and so on, to make 12 combinations (12 is just arbitrary, some animals eat more varieties and some only eat one). I think I need to make a dummy variable of `Block x Variety` and then assign the desired `eater`. Eventually, I want to make contrasts of eaters in each variety.

```
eater <- factor(c("fox", "cat","mouse","frog"), levels = c("fox", "cat","frog", "mouse"))
```

How do I proceed? The `add_grouping` example had single factor reconstruction only. What if the levels of `Block` is not divisible by the levels of `Variety`? For example, `Block` has 9 levels and `Variety` has 4 levels.https://rdrr.io/cran/emmeans/man/add_grouping.html

```
fiber.lm <- lm(strength ~ diameter + machine, data = fiber)
( frg <- ref_grid(fiber.lm) )

# Suppose the machines are two different brands
brands <- factor(c("FiberPro", "FiberPro", "Acme"), levels = c("FiberPro", "Acme"))
( gfrg <- add_grouping(frg, "brand", "machine", brands) )
```

Side issue: Where did `rep.meas = multivariate response levels: 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6` come from? There is no such column in `View(MOats)`.

I haven't figured out how to construct a new variable in the form of Factor1 = Factor2*Factor3 from the source code here https://rdrr.io/github/rvlenth/emmeans/src/R/ref-grid.R. Any leads are much appreciated.

UPDATE: The following lines added the new grouping variables but removed the original grouping variables, `Variety` and `Block`.

```
eater <- rep(LETTERS[1:3],6)
RG_add2 <- add_grouping(RG, "eater", "BV", eater)
RG_add2
'emmGrid' object with variables:
    BV = 6 G, 5 G, 3 G, 4 G, 2 G, 1 G, 6 M, 5 M, 3 M, 4 M, 2 M, 1 M, 6 V, 5 V, 3 V, 4 V, 2 V, 1 V
    rep.meas = multivariate response levels: 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6
    eater = A, B, C
Nesting structure:  BV %in% eater


RG_add <- add_grouping(RG, "eater", "BVlev", eater)  
Error in add_grouping(RG, "eater", "BVlev", eater) : 
  Length of 'newlevs' doesn't match # levels of 'BVlev'
```

I don't understand the error, because

```
length(BV)
[1] 18
 length(eater)
[1] 18
BV
 [1] "6 G" "5 G" "3 G" "4 G" "2 G" "1 G" "6 M" "5 M" "3 M" "4 M" "2 M" "1 M"
[13] "6 V" "5 V" "3 V" "4 V" "2 V" "1 V"
BVlev
 [1] "6 G" "5 G" "3 G" "4 G" "2 G" "1 G" "6 M" "5 M" "3 M" "4 M" "2 M" "1 M"
[13] "6 V" "5 V" "3 V" "4 V" "2 V" "1 V"
```

Eventually, I want to do `emmeans(RG_add, ~ Variety|eater)`

Comment: I don't understand the main question fully yet, but the side issue is easy. MOats has a multivariate response variable, and rep.meas is the name given to the levels of the multivariate response -- as documented.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see the nitrogen levels until I `str(MOats)`. `View(MOats)` doesn't give me the full set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `add_grouping()` function currently requires a single nested factor. So you need to create that one factor. That may be done using the `levels<-` method:

```r
library(emmeans)
MOats.lm = lm(yield ~ Block + Variety, data = MOats)

RG = ref_grid(MOats.lm)
RG
## 'emmGrid' object with variables:
##     Block = VI, V, III, IV, II, I
##     Variety = Golden Rain, Marvellous, Victory
##     rep.meas = multivariate response levels: 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6

BVlev = do.call(paste, expand.grid(c(6, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1), c("G", "M", "V")))

levels(RG) = list(BV = BVlev, rep.meas = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6))
RG
## 'emmGrid' object with variables:
##     BV = 6 G, 5 G, 3 G, 4 G, 2 G, 1 G, 6 M, 5 M, 3 M, 4 M, 2 M, 1 M, 6 V, 5 V, 3 V, 4 V, 2 V, 1 V
##     rep.meas = multivariate response levels: 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Now you can proceed with `add_grouping(RG, "eater", "VB", eaters)`. The length of `eaters` must be 18, such that each element specifies which eater is associated with each level of `BV`.

When replacing the levels, you need to be careful to preserve the relative order of the factors in the list of levels. The factors being combined need to be consecutive.

Comment: I saw your answer just after I updated my question. I'll report back.

Comment: Oops, I need to make a couple of small corrections to the answer. Hold on...

Comment: Thank you. Why is the `nitro` variable "hidden" from `View(MOats)`? The `rep.meas` in `levels(RG) = list(BV = BVlev, rep.meas = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6))` would make more sense to me if it weren't.

Comment: I have no idea as I've never used View. But it is not hidden if you do help("MOats")

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my issue. I had the eaters added but `Variety` and `Block` disappeared.

Comment: Right. Unfortunately, you currently can't have it both ways without hacking the slots in the object.

Comment: I would appreciate that feature.  `pwpp(emmeans(RG_add, ~ Variety|eater))` would be much more presentable than large tables of contrasts.

Comment: Please see [this issue](https://github.com/rvlenth/emmeans/issues/286) on the **emmeans** repository. I have extended `add_grouping()` to support more than one reference factor.  But be careful what you wish for. If you want comparisons of `Variety|eater`, you'll be averaging over `Block`, and you will only get estimates in cases where all 6 blocks have the same eater. What *would* work nicely would be comparisons of eaters. You can install the revised package from GitHub, then see the new example for `add_grouping`.

Comment: And yes, `emmeans(RG_add, ~ eater | Variety)` is more reasonable.